# Haskell: Code randomly prints out invocation

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider this Haskell code which simplifies a boolean expression by mashing it to NAND's (like on a circuit board) and then reconstructs it:
https://gist.github.com/kvanberendonck/5862432/c3c059138701fe127e556a2ca3696fe11c091252

When compiled with GHC 7.4.2 I get the following output on my Windows system:

```
Before:
And (Or (Not (Input 1)) (And (And (Input 2) (Input 1)) (Input 3))) (Not (Or (Inp
ut 1) (And (Input 2) (Input 4))))

Mash:
Nand (Nand (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 1) (Input 1)) (Nand (Input 1) (Input 1))) (N
and (Nand (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 2) (Input 1)) (Nand (Input 2) (Input 1))) (In
put 3)) (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 2) (Input 1)) (Nand (Input 2) (Input 1))) (Inpu
t 3))) (Nand (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 2) (Input 1)) (Nand (Input 2) (Input 1)))
(Input 3)) (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 2) (Input 1)) (Nand (Input 2) (Input 1))) (I
nput 3))))) (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 1) (Input 1)) (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 2) (
Input 4)) (Nand (Input 2) (Input 4))) (Nand (Nand (Input 2) (Input 4)) (Nand (In
put 2) (Input 4))))) (Nand (Nand (Input 1) (Input 1)) (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 2
) (Input 4)) (Nand (Input 2) (Input 4))) (Nand (Nand (Input 2) (Input 4)) (Nand
(Input 2) (Input 4))))))) (Nand (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 1) (Input 1)) (Nand (In
put 1) (Input 1))) (Nand (Nand (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 2) (Input 1)) (Nand (Inp
ut 2) (Input 1))) (Input 3)) (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 2) (Input 1)) (Nand (Input
 2) (Input 1))) (Input 3))) (Nand (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 2) (Input 1)) (Nand (
Input 2) (Input 1))) (Input 3)) (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 2) (Input 1)) (Nand (In
put 2) (Input 1))) (Input 3))))) (Nand (Nand (Nand (Input 1) (Input 1)) (Nand (N
and (Nand (Input 2) (Input 4)) (Nand (Input 2) (Input 4))) (Nand (Nand (Input 2)
 (Input 4)) (Nand (Input 2) (Input 4))))) (Nand (Nand (Input 1) (Input 1)) (Nand
 (Nand (Nand (Input 2) (Input 4)) (Nand (Input 2) (Input 4))) (Nand (Nand (Input
 2) (Input 4)) (Nand (Input 2) (Input 4)))))))

After:
simpl.exe:
```

From my perspective the `After: simpl.exe` makes no sense. It seems to be the program invocation. I can't understand what's happening. Please advise.

Comment: `simple.exe:` is displaying an empty error message, surely caused by your `error []` call.  `error` takes a string as an argument, and since `String = [Char]`, `[]` is the same as the empty string.

Comment: OH! Thanks, haha. I guess the impossible error case isn't so impossible!

Comment: @luqui: you should post that as an answer.